# Heroku timeout registration start

Tags: heroku, timeout, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip, dropzone

I have a simple question but can't really figure out how it really works: I don't know when the Heroku timeout starts to register..

I am uploading images into an AWS bucket but it goes first through Heroku's Rails application in order to resize and create different variants of the image (with Paperclip gem).

Then.. would the timeout starts to register at the very beginning a user starts to upload an image, or only when the image is received by the Rails application ..

If it is the former, then I think I need to upload to AWS first. But if it is the latter (then not relying on user bandwith) I think I can keep the current scheme ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout starts as soon as the request is received by Heroku's router.

On ruby apps, each instance of the app can only process one request. There are way to handle concurrent requests with workers (processes) and threads of course. But each worker/threads will still be able to process only one request.

This means ruby isn't awesome at handling long-running requests. So uploading files directly to S3 will always bring you more scalability.

It's actually the way Heroku recommends to do it: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails

Comment: Thanks a lot Damien. Actually I don't mind if my user has to wait to see the images being uploaded. Because he has to get the different variants available straight away.  I was just scared that he couldn't even upload heavy images (like 10 MB png images). If I understand well, it is then fine ...?

Comment: It is just when the file has been received by controller that the Imagemagick processing of all variants should not last more than 30 seconds .. (and actual upload doesnt count towards these 30 secs .. )

Comment: Aww it changes everything. It may be difficult to deal this way because an ADSL connexion may struggle to upload 10MB in 30 secs.. I was confused with Heroku document, it mentions both the router as a first point, then the dyno .. Not very clear. Thanks for clarification.